# Function to plot model with one variable varying and others constant

Tags: r, plot, regression, data-visualization

It's simple, but I can't remember how this procedure is called, hence I was not able to find the function to do so. I want to explore the effects and gradients of a simple lm() model by plotting the response of one variable at a time, the others being kept constant.

Can anybody tell me which function to use to do so? I seem to remember it's a function generating several plots, or something like this. It could be something akin to sensitivity analysis... Sorry for the beginner question.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `termplot`, and set the `par(mfrow=c(2,2))` or whatever beforehand

Comment: This seems to work, however the crPlots function seems to do the trick even better. Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`car`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/car/car.pdf) package has a lot of utilities for analyzing regression models. This sounds like a component+residual plot (or [partial residuals plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_residual_plot)).

```
library(car)   # for avPlots(...)
fit <- lm(mpg~wt+hp+disp, mtcars)
crPlots(fit)
```

[image]

As noted in the comments, `termplot(...)` does basically the same thing.

Comment: Just a little question: is it possible to obtain this sort of graphic but plotting againt the response variable directly instead of the component+residuals?